# How to make font-family cursive in visual studio code?

Tags: css, fonts

I am attempting to make the font-family cursive using visual studio code. I am starting a boot camp so experience level is zero. I have tried multiple things and can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

settings > text editor > font > font family > cursive

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdcRO.png)

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thought you were asking how to make Visual Studio Code show cursive in the text editor itself.  You have tagged CSS and Fonts, however, so I will answer how to make a CSS font-family property be cursive.  If this is not the answer you are looking for please let me know.

There are several cursive font families to choose from.  This example uses "Brush Script MT" and fallback family values.  I am targeting all paragraph tags with this, you will need to decide if you want to narrow the focus to a more specific/different Tag, Id, or Class.

For simplicity sake, I am using Internal CSS (CSS rules defined at top of HTML page).  In a real-world application, you would typically use External CSS, in which an HTML page will reference a separate CSS page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: linen;
}

h1 {
  color: maroon;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Brush Script MT', 'Brush Script Std', cursive;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a cursive paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

These are the sites I found to reference, you should look them up for more detailed research.  Note: I have provided a link to a page that shows several different cursive font-families, in my tests, not all of them worked for me.  It is always important to test your work and to test in different browsers and versions of browsers that you plan on supporting.

- [List of CSS Font-Family options](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts.en.html)
- [CSS font-family property tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp)
- [How to add CSS to HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)
- [An online HTML/CSS test page](http://www.cssdesk.com/)

Focusing on the Visual Studio Code portion of the question, you may add an extension that allows you to see a live preview of your HTML/CSS page.  I found a quick video that is easy to follow which shows you how to install and use this extension.  If you copy and paste the provided html page into an HTML file in VS Code, you can see the CSS Cursive font family in action.

[Live preview HTML code in browser with Visual Studio Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nr-QTde0NA)

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I am going to try it now!

Comment: @Philip-Perkins Great!  If it works for you please remember to mark as answered.  If not, please ask for further clarification.  Once you get going I would recommend learning how to put your CSS into an external file, as well as learning how to target HTML tags (as we did above with the p tag), targeting an ID, and targeting a class with CSS.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go to -

> `settings` > `text editor` > `font` > `font family`

then type

> **`'Fira Code iScript'`**

First you need to download & install the font in your system, if not present.